# Magento 1.4 installer script is not firing

Tags: magento-1.4, install-script

my config.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Premium_PlatinumBlock>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Premium_PlatinumBlock>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <premium_platinumblock>
                <class>Premium_PlatinumBlock_Helper</class>
            </premium_platinumblock>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <premium_platinumblock_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Premium_PlatinumBlock</module>
                </setup>
            </premium_platinumblock_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

my installer script -

```
Premium/PlatinumBlock/sql/premium_platinumblock_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$storeId    = 2;
$type       = 'block';
$title      = 'Block123';
$identifier = 'my_block';
$content = <<<'EOD here'
EOD;

Mage::getModel('cms/'.$type)
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->load($identifier)
        ->setTitle($title)
        ->setIdentifier($identifier)
        ->setStores(array($storeId))
        ->setIsActive(true)
        ->setContent($content)
        ->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: try replacing <module>premium_PlatinumBlock</module> by  <module>Premium_PlatinumBlock</module>

Comment: this is just a typing mistake here. Its not working out. is it different for magento 1.4

Comment: Just to be sure, there is a file `app/etc/modules/Premium_PlatinumBlock.xml` where it says that the extension is active? Also check the `core_resource` table in the database and check if your extension is listed there and check the version of the extension. If that's already 1.0.0 or higher, your installer will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Here I was missing the class in setup, that's why it was not running. I fixed it like

```
    <resources>
        <platinumblock_setup >
            <setup>
                <module>PlatinumBlock</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </platinumblock_setup >
    </resources>
</global>
```